# Problem with jquery script in cshtml (.NET MVC5)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with jquery script (I'm just starting to learn jQuery).

Each time I save a workout by clicking the SaveWorkout button, the data sent in the exercises array is multiplied in some way.
For example, I have saved 2 workouts with one exercise, then when I want to save third workout with one exercise, 3 the same exercises are sent in the array(table in cshtml - #detailsTable).
In addition, e.g. when I have saved 2 workouts with one exercise, when I want to save third workout with two exercises, the same 3 exercises are multiplied by 2 and a total of six exercises are sent in the array.
I tried somehow to clear the table with remove () or empty () but that doesn't help.

Where could the problem be?

Thanks everyone for help

Below i atached  my cshtml and controller.

```
<script>
    //Show Modal.
    function addNewOWorkout() {
        $("#newWorkoutModal").modal();
    }
    //Add Multiple Exercise.
    $("#addToList").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($.trim($("#exerciseName").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#numberOfRepetitions").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#weight").val()) == "") return;

        var exerciseName = $("#exerciseName").val(),
            numberOfRepetitions = $("#numberOfRepetitions").val(),
            weight = $("#weight").val(),
            detailsTableBody = $("#detailsTable tbody");

        var exerciseItem = '<tr><td>' + exerciseName + '</td><td>' + numberOfRepetitions + '</td><td>' + weight + '</td></tr>';
        detailsTableBody.append(exerciseItem);            
        clearItem();
    });
    //After Add A New Order In The List, Clear Clean The Form For Add More Order.
    function clearItem() {
        $("#exerciseName").val('');
        $("#numberOfRepetitions").val('');
        $("#weight").val('');
    }
    // After Add A New Order In The List, If You Want, You Can Remove It.
    $(document).on('click', 'a.deleteItem', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $self = $(this);
        if ($(this).attr('data-itemId') == "0") {
            $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", "#ff6347").fadeOut(800, function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
    });
    //After Click Save Button Pass All Data View To Controller For Save Database
    function saveWorkout(data) {
        return $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Workout/SaveWorkout",
            data: data,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Błąd!")
            }
        });
    }
    //Collect Multiple Order List For Pass To Controller
    $("#saveWorkout").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var workoutArr = [];
        workoutArr.length = 0;            
        
        $.each($("#detailsTable tbody tr"), function () {
            workoutArr.push({
                Name: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                RepetitionsNumber: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                weight: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html()
            });
        });

        var data = JSON.stringify({
            workoutName: $("#workoutName").val(),
            exercises: workoutArr
        });

        

        $.when(saveWorkout(data)).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });


    });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="newWorkoutModal">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">                                          
                                        <h4>Dodaj nowy trening</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <form id="NewWorkoutForm">
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            <h5 style="color:#ff6347">Szczegóły treningu</h5>
                                            <hr />
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <input type="hidden" id="WorkoutID" />
                                                <div class="col-12">
                                                    <label class="control-label pb-2">
                                                        Nazwa treningu
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-10">
                                                        <input type="text" id="workoutName" name="workoutName" placeholder="" class="form-control" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <h5 style="margin-top:10px;color:#ff6347">Szczegóły ćwiczenia</h5>
                                            <hr />
                                            <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                @*<input type="hidden" id="OrderId" />*@
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <input type="hidden" id="ExerciseID" />
                                                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-10">
                                                        <label class="control-label pb-2">
                                                            Nazwa ćwiczenia
                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="text" id="exerciseName" name="exerciseName" placeholder="" class="form-control" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                                                        <label class="control-label pb-2">
                                                            Liczba powtórzeń
                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="text" id="numberOfRepetitions" name="numberOfRepetitions" placeholder="" class="form-control" />
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">
                                                        <label class="control-label pb-2">
                                                            Ciężar (kg)
                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" placeholder="" class="form-control" />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row pt-3 pb-3">
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                                                        <a id="addToList" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Dodaj do listy</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <table id="detailsTable" class="table">
                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th style="width:40%">Nazwa ćwiczenia</th>
                                                            <th style="width:15%">Liczba powtórzeń</th>
                                                            <th style="width:15%">Ciężar</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
                                            <button id="saveWorkout" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Zapisz trening</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

method in controller:

```
 public ActionResult SaveWorkout(string workoutName, Exercise[] exercises)
    {
        string result = "Błąd!";

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (workoutName != null || exercises != null)
        {
            Workout newWorkout = new Workout()
            {
                Name = workoutName,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = userId
            };
            db.Workouts.Add(newWorkout);
            db.SaveChanges();

            var workoutId = db.Workouts.OrderByDescending(w => w.WorkoutID).Select(r => r.WorkoutID).FirstOrDefault();
            foreach (var exercise in exercises)
            {
                Exercise newExercise = new Exercise()
                {
                    Name = exercise.Name,
                    RepetitionsNumber = exercise.RepetitionsNumber,
                    Weight = exercise.Weight,
                    WorkoutID = workoutId

                };
                db.Exercises.Add(newExercise);
                
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            result = "Sukces!";
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: You are calling SaveChanges twice.

Comment: In the backend you are always adding new workout-objects, you are never updating existing ones.

Comment: Yes I know about it. I don't want to update my training. I want to create new ones and save new exercises in it. But every time I add exercises to the list in javascript code, the exercises get multiplied in some way.
For example, when I add only one exercise to the list (in the javasript code it is the "workoutArr" variable, and in the back it is the "exercises" variable), multiple exercises are sent to the controller, e.g. two identical exercises, even though I added only one to the list.

Comment: *and in the backend it is the "exercises" variable

Answer (score 0):

You are calling db.SaveChanges two times.

```
 public ActionResult SaveWorkout(string workoutName, Exercise[] exercises)
    {
        string result = "Błąd!";

        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (workoutName != null || exercises != null)
        {
            Workout newWorkout = new Workout()
            {
                Name = workoutName,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                UserId = userId
            };
            db.Workouts.Add(newWorkout);
           // db.SaveChanges(); -- no need

            var workoutId = db.Workouts.OrderByDescending(w => w.WorkoutID).Select(r => r.WorkoutID).FirstOrDefault();
            foreach (var exercise in exercises)
            {
                Exercise newExercise = new Exercise()
                {
                    Name = exercise.Name,
                    RepetitionsNumber = exercise.RepetitionsNumber,
                    Weight = exercise.Weight,
                    WorkoutID = workoutId

                };
                db.Exercises.Add(newExercise);
                
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
            result = "Sukces!";
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have to call db.SaveChanges() twice. First I have to create new workout because I have to get ID new workout created  and then assign exercises from array "exercises" to him. Problem is with array "exercises" (method argument) becasue in this variable are multiply exercises. For example, when I add only one exercise to the list (in the javasript code it is the "workoutArr" variable, and in the backend it is the "exercises" variable), multiple exercises are sent to the controller, e.g. two identical exercises, even though I added only one to the list.